# ¿Cómo recoger la respuesta de Redsys con el iframe insite?

Tags: webservice, rest, iframe, tokens, msg

Estoy implementando en mi web con Laravel mediante la opción inSite de Redsys el iframe para poder hacer uso del formulario de la tarjeta en mi propio dominio, sin necesidad de que me redirija fuera de mi web, pues bien, siguiendo la información que facilita Redsys sobre cómo implementarlo ( https://pagosonline.redsys.es/conexion-insite.html ) mi código es el siguiente:

```
@extends('layouts.layoutMaster')

@section('cuerpo')

 <div id="card-form" />
    <form name="datos">
        <input type="hidden" id="token"></input>
        <input type="hidden" id="errorCode"></input>
        <a href="javascript:alert(document.datos.token.value + '--' + document.datos.errorCode.value)"> ver</a>
    </form>

    <script>
        function merchantValidationEjemplo() {
            //Insertar validaciones…
            alert("Esto son validaciones propias");
            return true;
        }


    //< !--Listener de recepción de ID de operación-- >
            window.addEventListener("message", function receiveMessage(event) {
                storeIdOper(event, "token", "errorCode", merchantValidationEjemplo);
            });



        function pedido() {
            return "pedido" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
        }
        getInSiteForm('card-form', '', '', '', '', 'Texto botón pago', '999008881', '1', pedido(), 'ES', true);

    </script>
@endsection
```

Lo que hace que me genere bien el iframe de la tarjeta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema viene que cuando introduzco la tarjeta de prueba que me facilita Redsys para el entorno de Test, supuestamente me tendría que devolver un token (idOper) el cual me debería de meter el valor de este en el input de tipo hidden con id "token" pero en su lugar me devuelve un código de error "msg18" que me introduce en el input hidden errorCode, el cual, no está recogido en la tabla de códigos de error de Redsys (https://pagosonline.redsys.es/conexion-insite.html) , sólo hay hasta el "msg17". A alguien más le ha pasado que me pueda echar una mano. Muchas gracias por adelantado !!!

Answer (score 1):

A mi me pasaba lo mismo y he cambiado mi entorno de desarrollo a http://localhost:8012 (que es una de los pocos permitidos) y ya he podido enviar la petición y recibir el ID de operación (token) de vuelta.

A partir de allí ya es otra historia porque hay que lanzar la operación de autorización mediante una petición REST que he implementado y ejecutado, pero no hay manera de que funcione ya que siempre me sale el error

> SIS0218: El comercio no permite operaciones seguras por las entradas "operaciones" o "WebService"

Y es dónde ahora mismo estoy estancado yo. Pero bueno... pasito a pasito.

Saludos.

Comment: ¿Conseguiste una solución? La documentación de Redsys deja mucho que desear.

Comment: Hola, en mi caso el problema venía siempre de la URL que realizaba las peticiones. Al parecer, por motivos de seguridad, cualquiera que sea la URL desde la cual realizamos las peticiones, deberán estar incluidas entre los "Dominios InSite permitidos" en el "Módulo de Administración". Generalmente quien se encarga de incluir estas URL, es el banco al que hay que llamar.
¡Suerte!

Answer (score 0):

El código de error **msg18** significa que tienes que añadir el dominio desde donde se está ejecutando el iframe a dominios permitidos InSite.

En mi caso, escribí un correo al email de soporte de Redsys para que lo pudieran añadir.

Comment: Buenos días Rayk,

En principio gracias por contestar pero creo que ese paso ya lo tengo hecho, de todos modos lo revisaré. Te comentaré con lo que sea el error para ayudar a posibles miembros.

Muchas Gracias !